# Find maximum subset of a graph

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I'm looking for an algorithm. Suppose we have a graph with vertices {A, B, C, D, E... } and each vertex may have multiple weighted edges to other vertices within the set (I'll make up an adjacency list as an example):

```
A: (B, 34), (C, 32), (E, 20)
B: (A, 30)
C: (C, 32),  (D, 41)
D: (B, 34), (A, 30), (E, 20)
E: (D, 41)
```

Edges to the same node ALWAYS have the same value.

I want to find the subset (of some fixed length) with the greatest sum of edge weights where an edge to a node is only counted once. In other words, in this example the greatest subset of length 2 is {C, D} with a value of 30 + 34 + 32 + 41 + 20 = 157 (it hits all the values). A is not included in this sum despite having the largest individual value, and summing it with any other node does not hit all the values.

For clarity, the subset of {C, E} is 32 + 41 = 73 (the edge to D is not counted twice).

Doing this via brute force is something like O(V!*lg(V)) due to finding combinations and a sort at the end. Is there any way this can be computed more efficiently?

Comment: `{A, C} with a value of 30 + 34 + 32 + 41 + 20 = 157` Where does the `30` come from if `A is not included in this sum` ?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been {C, D}. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll state what I've figured out so far. I haven't came up with any better worst case guarantees, but I came up with a pruning heuristic that is guaranteed to find the best solution. Suppose there are sets named x and y, each of size n (x can also be smaller than y though). If y is a subset of x, then there is a guarantee that any set that replaces x with y is at least as good as the set that uses y. It would take worst-case quadratic time to check if any sets are a superset, but if the vertices are expected to be similar (or similar after they are unioned) then this could lead to a computational time decrease.